# What is the point of creating a unit test with a Fake/ Stub Repository

Tags: unit-testing, tdd, repository

I have looked a similar questions on here and I think I get the gist of where people answers are heading but I need to confirm whether or not I should create pure unit tests with Stubbed repositories for my solution.

If I have the following Unit Test (created using Microsoft's Fake Assemblies and MSTest):

```
 [TestMethod]
 public void creating_user_returns_a_valid_id()
 {
     var userId = new Random().Next(1, 1000);

     var userRepository = new StubIDataEntityRepository<User>
     {
         CreateT0 = x =>
             {
                 return userId;
             }
     };

     var user = new User();

     var result = userRepository.CreateT0(user);

     Assert.AreEqual(result, userId);
 }
```

Now, I have been studying up on Unit Tests and I understand that a pure unit test must not cross any boundaries or responsibilities, hence the Stub. I understand that if I want to test that the creation of a user in my database really does turn a valid user Id, I need to create an integration test. So what, exactly, am I testing here? I know people say application logic and that's all very valid but surely I am creating a test that creates an id, tells the fake repository to return that Id from its Create method and then confirming that the Id returned from the Create method is the same value. It feels like I'm doing a whole lot of work for what is essentially the following:

x = 1, y = 1, assert.areequal(x,y)!!

Is the answer really about training the developer to design their code via TDD? If any of you TDD gurus out there can enlighten me, it would be much appreciated!

Kind Regards

Ben

Answer (score 10, accepted):

*You are not testing anything useful here.*

Every unit test has a so-called **System Under Test** (SUT). That's the class you want to test.
To test the SUT, you must not mock it, because you would than test the mock, not the SUT. And that is kinda pointless.

In your case, it looks like you want to test the repository, but you are also mocking the repository, making the test pointless.

You want to use a mocked repository in tests where the SUT is another class that *uses* the repository.

Testing the repository is most likely a task for an integration test. Repository methods that directly access the database can't be tested with a unit test.

Comment: +1, though personally I write unit tests that access the database. It may be more work but makes sure the code and database still match (which is especially useful when using an ORM.)

Comment: @Pedro: That's not a unit test anymore. It's an integration test. You are testing the integration of your application with your database.

Comment: @DanielHilgarth: your comment is as I understand - were I to access the database, it is no longer a unit test. What you're saying is that the above unit test is pointless because I am missing something valid to test between the Save and Assert. With that in mind, this suggests that there is no point in having a unit test that solely tests the result of a mock repository method. Am I right in that assertion?

Comment: @DanielHilgarth: following on from the previous comment, I suppose I could tweak the above test to make use of, for e.g., a UserUnitOfWork class that needed an instance of an IDataEntityRepository<User> to test that when I called the Save/ Create method on that, it returned the expected results - that would be where the mock repository would be useful - testing the concrete UnitOfWork (as long as that accepted an abstraction of the User Repository, rather than forcing a database call)

Comment: @DanielHilgarth: I agree that is testing more than just code, and not a true "unit" test, but it is still a valid test and usually not too difficult to code using NUnit (or similar) and letting the continuous integration server run those along with everything else.

Comment: @Pedro: Yes, you can write integration tests with the existing unit testing frameworks, that's correct. Actually, I am not aware of a framework specifically for integration tests. The point is not that it is testing more than "code", the point is that it is not a test in isolation. Integration tests tend to test a less focused part of the system - i.e. more components at once - and because of that take longer to execute, setup and cleanup. If the runtime is not a problem for your CI server, you certainly can run them alongside your unit tests, that's right.

Comment: @BenjaminJones: About your first comment: Yes, that is correct. Testing a mock is useless, because you are not using that mock in your production code. About your second comment: Yes, that also is correct.

Comment: Have marked this as the answer. Many thanks to both of you for your input :0

Answer (score 3):

By "mocking" or "stubbing" your data access, you ensure that your unit tests are **solely** evaluating the performance of your code. With a mock, you know *exactly* what data will be returned when called upon, and what format it should take. You might not be the only one writing to your database or datafiles, and so your test results may subtly vary and leave you scratching your head.

In the process industry this concept is referred to as **isolation testing**, which gives a better sense (IMHO) of what one is trying to achieve in a unit test. What you say about "doing a whole lot of work" is valid when you're just starting a project, but project complexity is a form of entropy: it only gets worse the longer you run with it. Getting into good practices early on may save you some debugging nightmares further down the line.

Hope that helps :)

Answer (score 0):

The question is crafted very nicely.. and my answer is if your nose smells something questionable, it probably is.

If you app interfaces with a DB, you should be delegating the DB access to a Role (usually called a XXXRepository) where XXX is the type of resource being persisted (e.g. Customer).

- Now if you want to test the implementation of the XXXRepository, you should be writing integration tests (i.e. tests that verify that the rest of the app integrates with the DB subsystem). In other words, are the terms of the contract (XXXRepository) are being met. Hence the name 'contract tests'.
- If you are testing the code in the 'rest of the app' section, you should be writing unit tests and mocking out the XXXRepository role for reasons of isolation and speed.

To put it simply, if your SUT has the responsibility of writing to a file - your tests should be calling the SUT methods and verifying that the file changed accordingly. Anything else.. and we're just setting up for surprises later.